# how to properly use JOIN?

Tags: mysql, database, join

I have two tables and a foreign_key index table:
    table xymply_locations
    id
    name
    lat
    lng

```
table xymply_categories
id
name

table xymply_categoryf_key
locid
catid
```

and i want to select the categories that are assigned to locid 1. How do I do this, I tried

```
SELECT * 
FROM `xymply_categoryf_key`, xymply_categories 
JOIN `xymply_categories` ON
        xymply_categories.id = xymply_categoryf_key.catid 
WHERE locid = 1;
```

but I get `"Not unique table/alias: 'xymply_categories' "` and I'm wondering why...?

Comment: You'd actually doing TWO joins, one implicity with the two `from` tables, and one explicity with the `join`. So you've got xymply_categories included twice, causing your error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing implicit (all tables listed in the FROM clause) and explicit JOIN styles in your code, hence the error.

```
SELECT xc.id, xc.name
    FROM xymply_categories xc
        INNER JOIN xymply_categoryf_key xck
            ON xc.id = xck.catid
    WHERE xck.locid = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

In your query, you're selecting from two tables. One of them is `xymply_categoryf_key`, the other is a `JOIN` of two instances of `xymply_categories`. You're using two instances of the same table, so when you write `xymply_categories.id` it is not clear which instance you mean - the one that is the first argument of `JOIN`, or that one which is the second argument? That's what `"Not unique table/alias"` means. If I understand correctly what you want to do, try this:

```
SELECT c.id, c.name FROM xymply_categories c, xymply_categoryf_key k WHERE c.id = k.catid AND k.locid = 1;
```

This was done without JOIN, although the evaluation of

```
WHERE c.id = k.catid
```

maybe would be faster with `JOIN`, I am not sure. Also, note the usage of `k` and `c` as aliases for the tables `xymply_categoryf_key` (`k` for key) and `xymply_categories c` (`c` for categories). This is how to avoid the problem of "Not unique table/alias" which occured to you before. In your case, you would use e.g.

```
xymply_categories a JOIN xymply_categories b WHERE a.id = ...
```

So, although I gave an example how to write the query without using `JOIN` - as I mentioned, using `JOIN` will maybe produce a faster query. Therefore, all you should do is to add the aliases.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are "joining" xymply_catagories twice so the db wants an alias for the tables in order to know which one to go to when selecting a column.

you can do joins several ways depending on what you want.   A straight inner join (which appears to be what you want) can be

```
select * from xymply_categoryf_key a, xymply_categories b where a.catid = b.id 
WHERE b.locid = 1;
```

or you can also do an explicit inner join as Joe Stefanelli shows.    Either of these gives you the records where there is matching info from each table.